# User Mobile number using facebook android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I am working on android application using parse.com services. I am login through users credentials but after login i want to get the users number from facebook just like email address, last name. Please guide me a way to get user mobile number using android platform

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook has retracted these features of the API due to privacy concerns.

Source: [Here](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2011/jan/18/facebook-privacy-data)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the mobile number of a Facebook user via the Graph API. Even not if the user set it to public.
Please refer this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/#fields